# If controller is not working.I have used IF controller for running HTTP Requests depending on previous request results

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am new to Jmeter. Here is the structure of the API's.

[image: Structure][1]

I want to test the script with 500 users. If my login API is passed for 400 users then I want to run the 'Get Media Gallery' API for only those 400 users only so I have used IF controller for that. Here is the screenshot for the IF controller.

[image: IF Controller]

But even I am getting the JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true, My If the controller is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use without quotes

```
 ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

[image]

Or use `__groovy` as suggested if performance is an issue